# Is there a way to get precise coordinates for Photoshop object anchor point

Tags: adobe-photoshop

When modifying the anchor point of an object, is there away to get the coordinates of the anchor point either relative to to the object coordinates or to the global coordinates ?

Comment: Could you give some more details about what exactly you are trying to do? I'm sure it would be possible to script something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i don't think so, but it's probably a lot easier to use intersecting guides to pinpoint a location.

Comment: Good idea, unfortunately the pivot point disappears whenever I try to do something else (such as placing the guides)

Comment: (And I do need to place the pivot point to graphically ensure the object pivots around the good point)

Comment: Objects do not have anchors, its only a temporary pivot for the tool. So no you can not do this. Perhaps you should be looking into using AE or Flash? Use a grid.